# Disable DataTable change tracking

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

Is there a way to have data tables automatically accept changes or just disable change tracking when making modifications to rows?

When making changes to a datatable, forgetting to call `DataTable.AcceptChanges()` can cause a real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the whole point of a `DataTable` is to have the added benefits of row versioning and change tracking. I do not think you can actually disable this behavior. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows.aspx):

> Each DataRow in the collection represents a row of data in the table.
>   To commit a change to the value of a column in the row, you must
>   invoke the AcceptChanges method.

Do you want to disable row versioning completely or only in specific occasions?

Comment: I want to disable it completely.

Comment: "forgetting to call DataTable.AcceptChanges()..."  Forgetting to call ANY function can cause problems.  If it's really that difficult, you could create your own function MySaveDataTable(...) that called AcceptChanges for you.